# java.sql.SQLException: Already closed

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat

We have a webapp running in production on tomcat with a MySQL back-end. All was fine for sometime, then suddenly we started getting this exception `java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.`

The entire stack trace is:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Could not close JDBC Connection    
java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:294)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:428)
    at com.nokia.analytics.aws.aggregate.service.importer.DBInsert.truncateTable(DBInsert.java:135)
    at com.blah.analytics.aggregate.service.importer.AggregateCollector.pullAndInsert(AggregateCollector.java:85)
    at com.blah.analytics.aggregate.service.importer.AggregateCollector.call(AggregateCollector.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

We are using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` as our datasource. I searched quite a bit but to no avail.
It doesn't occur always and hence is very hard to reproduce. It seems a problem with db connection pooling. Somewhere it was suggested to set [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#maxActive) param as negative. Currently we are not changing of those parameters (all have default vals).

What approach should we follow to avoid it?

EDIT:

The relevant code is in (DBInsert.java)

133:    `String sql = "DELETE FROM "+tableName;`

134:    `logger.debug(sql);`

135:    `this.jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);`

(133-135 are line nos. which are specified in the exception)

My datasource config:

```
<bean id="bisToolDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="${url}/blah_db?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true" />
        <property name="username" value="${uname}" />
        <property name="password" value="${passwd}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: I don't know what causes it, but it is a bug, [`Connection.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) should not throw an exception if already closed: _"Calling the method `close` on a `Connection` object that is already closed is a no-op"_

Answer (score 18):

The cause of this problem is connection isn't used in a long time, add `testOnBorrow` and `validationQuery` property to your datasource configuration then your application will work fine. 
Good luck:)

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right in spotting the problem. I had already figured out that problem was related to the connection pooling and turned off connection pooling.

Comment: Well the only reason I didn't accept is because I didn't try out the approach suggested by you...

Comment: @HarshalWaghmare , would like to ask what do you means by turned off connection pooling? My application is running on IBM WAS, and using db2 as database. Mostly what I see the connection pool setting can do is about the maximum connection and minimum connect size. But not understand about the turned off setting, can advice?

Answer (score 7):

As user *NobodyElse* pointed out, the problem was related to connection pooling. I was using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` as datasource. The nature of the application is such that there is spurt of connections at some fixed time in the day and no connections at all for the entire day. So due to this connections in the pool were getting stale and when next day application tried to connect to DB, we were getting this exception.

There are basically two solutions to this:
The one pointed out by *NobodyElse*, that is to use `testOnBorrow`; details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125962/correct-way-to-keep-pooled-connections-alive-or-time-them-out-and-get-fresh-one)

The other solution (which I employed for our app) is to turn off pooling completely. Note do this only when the application is not DB intensive (which was true in our case). So I switched to `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`. The config for which it seems to be working fine is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="${url}/blah_db?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true" />
        <property name="username" value="${uname}" />
        <property name="password" value="${passwd}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: FYI...."DriverManagerDataSource" is not really connection pool. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html