# grails app terminates after some idle time – what triggers unexpected shutdown?

Tags: grails, shutdown

I've got a Grails 2.4.3 app for internal use in my company.
Problem is, after some time when I had it running (`grails dev run-app`), it terminates  listening without prior notice:

```
INFO  [Thread-3]: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
INFO  [Thread-3]: Stopping service Tomcat
### Shutting down.
INFO  [Thread-3]: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
INFO  [Thread-3]: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

(The 3rd line is from the destroy() method in my BootStrap.groovy)

For datasource connections, there are [keepalive strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125962/correct-way-to-keep-pooled-connections-alive-or-time-them-out-and-get-fresh-one) for pooled connections. I'd like the grails app to stay online, too.

How can I investigate on what causes the server to stop listening?
Is this a common issue and can it be solved by config?

***Edit:***

The root logger shows the following on DEBUG level:

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-4]: Counting down[http-bio-8080-exec-4] latch=2
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1]: Error parsing HTTP request header
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
...
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1]: Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@5c0b659a:Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=58705,localport=8080]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-1]: Counting down[http-bio-8080-exec-1] latch=1
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1421320212649 sessioncount 0
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1421320272661 sessioncount 0
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1421320332673 sessioncount 0
DEBUG [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]]: End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0]: Counting up[http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0] latch=1
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-6]: Error parsing HTTP request header
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:519)
...
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-6]: Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@674b5757:Socket[addr=/10.41.2.116,port=46215,localport=8080]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-6]: Counting down[http-bio-8080-exec-6] latch=1
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardServer[-1]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardServer[-1]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardService[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
INFO  [Thread-3]: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: About to unlock socket for:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Socket unlock completed for:localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0]: Counting down[http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0] latch=0
INFO  [Thread-3]: Stopping service Tomcat
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardService[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve[Tomcat]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [Thread-3]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Unregister host [localhost] at domain [null] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve[localhost]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve[localhost]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [Tomcat-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Unregister Context [/workspent] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Unregister Wrapper [grails-errorhandler] in Context [/workspent] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPING]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails-errorhandler]] to [STOPPED]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Setting state for [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/workspent].StandardWrapper[grails]] to [STOPPING_PREP]
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-2]: Unregister Wrapper [grails] in Context [/workspent] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
INFO  [localhost-startStop-2]: ### Shutting down. Current time is 2015-01-15T12:12:39.009+01:00
INFO  [localhost-startStop-2]: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
```

Comment: From my experience this is not a common issue. Can you try increasing the log verbosity by setting the root logger level to debug or even trace? See [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) for instructions.

Comment: Did the JVM crash? Did it generate a `hs_err_pid` file? This link helped me understand the dump log contents: https://www.fullcontact.com/blog/java-runtime-memory-use/

Comment: Thanks for your advices so far, I'll look further into it after the season vacations ;)

Comment: @SalvadorValencia From my understanding it cannot be a JVM crash as the application runs through the rest of the shutdown normally.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your `stacktrace.log` file, probably some error will be there.
As the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html) says:

> When exceptions occur, there can be an awful lot of noise in the
>   stacktrace from Java and Groovy internals. Grails filters these
>   typically irrelevant details and restricts traces to non-core
>   Grails/Groovy class packages.
>
> When this happens, the full trace is always logged to the StackTrace
>   logger, which by default writes its output to a file called
>   stacktrace.log

If you don't know where is your file, you can configure it through log4j: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html

In your `Config.groovy`:

```
error stdout: "StackTrace"
log4j = {
    appenders {
        rollingFile name: "stacktrace", maxFileSize: 1024,
                    file: "/var/tmp/logs/myApp-stacktrace.log"
    }
}
```

Comment: Grails filters the stack traces so they are shorter, but the error itself would still be reported!

Comment: Sometimes some errors don't appear in the grails output, this is why i said to you to see your `stacktrace.log`

Comment: Which exceptions appear in the output depends on the configured logger levels, but those same rules apply for `stacktrace.log`. The only difference is in the stack trace detail (full stack traces appear in `stacktrace.log`) but OP is not getting any errors at all!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem for some time now after the holidays, anyways I gave +1 for the hint regarding the log4j config.

Comment: Being more patient, now I was able to extract the debug output as such a shutdown has happened again today. I added the log outputs.